# Select n amount of random rows where n is proportionate to each value's % of total population

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I have a table of 58 million customer records. Each customer has a market value (EN, US, FR etc.)

I'm trying to select a 100k sample set which contains customers from every market. The ratio of customers per market in the sample must match the ratios in the actual table.

So if UK customers account for 15% of the records in the customer table then there must be 15k UK customers in the 100k sample set and the same then for each market.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

First, a simple random sample should do pretty well on representing the market sizes.  What you are asking for is a stratified sample.

One way to get such a sample is to order the data randomly and assign a sequential number in each group.  Then normalize the sequential number to be between 0 and 1, and finally order by the normalized value and choose the top "n" rows:

```
select top 100000 c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by market order by rand(checksum(newid()))
                               ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by market) as cnt
      from customers c
     ) c
order by cast(seqnum as float) / cnt
```

It may be clear what is happening if you look at the data.  Consider taking a sample of 5 from:

```
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    D
6    D
7    B
8    A
9    D
10   C
```

The first step assigns a sequential number randomly within each market:

```
1    A      1
2    B      1
3    C      1
4    D      1
5    D      2
6    D      3
7    B      2
8    A      2   
9    D      4
10   C      2
```

Next, normalize these values:

```
1    A      1      0.50
2    B      1      0.50
3    C      1      0.50
4    D      1      0.25
5    D      2      0.50
6    D      3      0.75
7    B      2      1.00
8    A      2      1.00
9    D      4      1.00
10   C      2      1.00
```

Now, if you take the top 5, you will get the first five values which is a stratified sample.

Comment: I've tried your query and it seems there's an error near `newid()`. Is `end` necessary? Because on SQL Server 2008 it mark that as an error (and the `)` after too).

Answer (score 1):

Using a sample that big a casual extraction will give you a sample with good statitical approximation of the original population, as pointed out by Gordon Linoff.

To force the equal percentage between the population and the sample you can calculate and use all the needed parameter: the dimension of the population and the dimension of the partition, with the addition of a random ID.

```
Declare @sampleSize INT
Set @sampleSize = 100000

With D AS (
  SELECT customerID
       , Country
       , Count(customerID) OVER (PARTITION BY Null) TotalData
       , Count(customerID) OVER (PARTITION BY Country) CountryData
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Country 
                            ORDER BY rand(checksum(newid()))) ID
  FROM   customer
)
SELECT customerID
     , Country
FROM   D
WHERE  ID <= Round((Cast(CountryData as Float) / TotalData) * @sampleSize, 0)
ORDER BY Country
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d10c2/15) with less data.

Be aware that the approximation of the function in the `WHERE` condition can make the returned data a little less or a little more of the desired one, for example in the demo the rows returned are 9 instead of 10.